# Is it possible to automatically run a function on django app thru settings.py?

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I have this function on my views.py, I need to automatically runs it after I run `python manage.py runserver` a guy said that I must run that function it on `settings.py`. I tried it but I can't import the views & models to my settings.py (maybe because im noob?) so I can't do what he suggested.

This is the process, I have a toggle button for enabling and disabling `auto_sms` function on my frontend javascript(`vuejs`).

if I pick `enable` it will call the API endpoint of `auto_sms` thru axios. like do this in a while loop, check in every 30 mins then repeat until get executed then reset. wait for another condition to be valid. `responses.count()`

if I pick `disable` it will call the API endpoint of `disable_sms` thru axios (I haven't started coding this yet). like if its detects that `auto_sms is true` then make it false.

I want to ask, is my imagination for my application is possible to happen?

@models.py

```
class Rainfall(models.Model):
    level = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, default='')
    amount = models.FloatField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def update_level(self):
        if 0.1 <= self.amount < 2.5:
            return 'Light'
        elif 2.5 <= self.amount < 7.5:
            return 'Moderate'
        elif 7.5 < self.amount < 15:
            return 'Heavy'
        elif 15 <= self.amount < 30:
            return 'Intense'
        elif 30 <= self.amount < 50:
            return 'Torrential'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.level:
            self.level = self.update_level()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)



class Sms(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

@views.py

```
def send_sms(request):
    z = Rainfall.objects.latest('timestamp')
    numbers = Mobile.objects.all()
    message = (f'Test: ({z.timestamp})')

    account_sid = '**********'
    auth_token = '*********'

    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
    for i in numbers:
        client.messages.create(to=i.mobile_number,
                               from_='********',
                               body=message)

    record = Sms.objects.create(description=f'{message}')
    record.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/', 200)


def auto_sms(request):
    responses = Rainfall.objects.filter(
        level='Torrential' or 'Intense',
        timestamp__gt=now() - timedelta(days=1),
    )
    if responses.count() >= 5:
        send_sms(request)

    return HttpResponse(200)
```

Comment: Do you need a task to run periodically in background even when no user is active ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Redis + Celery and Django together.

simply,

If you have a task,then send it to Redis from Django,after a certain time/according to your commands it will ask celery to run it.

Google more about them.

[https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/celery-redis-django#:~:text=Redis%20is%20a%20message%20broker,to%20make%20real%2Dtime%20magic](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/celery-redis-django#:%7E:text=Redis%20is%20a%20message%20broker,to%20make%20real%2Dtime%20magic).

Comment: After I sent it to redis, is it possible to disable it thru toggle button?

Comment: Yes it is possible, to get Hawk view, please study how it works with other resources, Celery is a task queue with focus on real-time processing, while also supporting task scheduling.

Redis is a message broker. This means it handles the queue of "messages" between Django and Celery.